# Data hiding in Python implementation written in C

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python 2.7 tutorial [section 9.4](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks)  it says:

> In fact, nothing in Python makes it possible to enforce data hiding —
>   it is all based upon convention. (On the other hand, the Python
>   implementation, written in C, can completely hide implementation
>   details and control access to an object if necessary; this can be used
>   by extensions to Python written in C.)

My question is how Python implementation hides implementation details of objects. How it can be used in extensions to Python written in C?

Please also include code examples in answers.

Answer (score 0):

Because an extension written in C has total control over attribute access and can have data in the object that won't be accessible from python. Read [Extending and Embedding](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/index.html) for details, especcially the chapter on defining new types.